# add columns dynamically to rowwise tibble throws 'must return compatible vectors across groups'

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to add columns to a tibble, such that their values depend on another column. Specifically my df contains a column named `category` and I have dictionary mapping its values to other column names. Thus, I'd like to add a column named `relevant_field_name1`, and a column named `relevant_field_val1`, such that their values will be row-specific. Ditto for `relevant_field_name2`, `relevant_field_val2`, etc.

```
library(collections)
cat2du_col <- dict()
cat2du_col$set('oncology', c('stage', 'is_solid'))
cat2du_col$set('covid19', c('saturation', 'is_vaccinated'))

cat_map <- function(df) {
  cols <- cat2du_col$get(df[['category']], NA)
  relevant_field_name1 <- cols[1]
  relevant_field_name2 <- cols[2]
  if (!is.na(relevant_field_name1)) {
    relevant_field_val1 <- df[[relevant_field_name1]]
  } else{
    relevant_field_val1 <- NA
  }
  if (!is.na(relevant_field_name2)) {
    relevant_field_val2 <- df[[relevant_field_name2]]
  } else{
    relevant_field_val2 <- NA
  }
  
    return(data.frame(relevant_field_name1, relevant_field_val1, relevant_field_name2, relevant_field_val2))

}

df <-
  tibble(
    category = c('oncology', 'covid19', 'other'),
    stage = c('I', NA, NA),
    is_solid = c(T, NA, NA),
    saturation = c(NA, 95, NA),
    is_vaccinated = c(T, F, T)
  )

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(cat_map(.data))
```

However the last row gives an error:

```
>  df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(cat_map(.data))
```

> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. ℹ `..1 = cat_map(.data)`. ℹ NAs introduced by
> coercion ℹ The warning occurred in row 3. Warning: Problem with
> `mutate()` input `..1`. ℹ `..1 = cat_map(.data)`. ℹ NAs introduced by
> coercion ℹ The warning occurred in row 3. Error: Problem with
> `mutate()` input `..1`. ℹ `..1 = cat_map(.data)`. x `..1` must return
> compatible vectors across groups Run `rlang::last_error()` to see
> where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem was that the values of the new columns had incompatible types, some were numeric and others - strings. I've solved it by converting all values to strings.

```
cat_map <- function(df) {
  cols <- cat2du_col$get(df[['category']], NA)
  relevant_field_name1 <- cols[1]
  relevant_field_name2 <- cols[2]
  if (!is.na(relevant_field_name1)) {
    relevant_field_val1 <- toString(df[[relevant_field_name1]])
  } else{
    relevant_field_val1 <- NA
  }
  if (!is.na(relevant_field_name2)) {
    relevant_field_val2 <- toString(df[[relevant_field_name2]])
  } else{
    relevant_field_val2 <- NA
  }
```