# Map a tibble column to another column by name

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a character column, `field_name`, which contains names of other columns. I'd like to create another column, `field_value`, that would contain values based on `field_name` on each row. If `field_name` is NA, `field_value` should be NA as well. I'm not interested in using `rowwise()` (for performance reasons).

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  category stage is_solid saturation is_vaccinated field_name
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>         <dbl> <lgl>         <chr>
1 oncology I     TRUE             NA TRUE          stage
2 covid19  NA    NA               95 FALSE         saturation
3 other    NA    NA               NA TRUE          NA
```

Expected Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  category stage is_solid saturation is_vaccinated field_name field_value
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>         <dbl> <lgl>         <chr>      <chr>
1 oncology I     TRUE             NA TRUE          stage      I
2 covid19  NA    NA               95 FALSE         saturation 95
3 other    NA    NA               NA TRUE          NA         NA
```

```
df <- 
    tibble(
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              category = c("oncology", "covid19", "other"),
                 stage = c("I", NA, NA),
              is_solid = c(TRUE, NA, NA),
            saturation = c(NA, 95, NA),
         is_vaccinated = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
            field_name = c("stage", "saturation", NA)
    )
```

Update: @deschen's answer doesn't work when we have other values in stage. E.g.,

```
df <- 
  tibble(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    category = c("oncology", "covid19", "other"),
    stage = c("I", "II", "III"),
    is_solid = c(TRUE, NA, NA),
    saturation = c(NA, 95, NA),
    is_vaccinated = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
    field_name = c("stage", "saturation", NA)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `field_name` values as a character vector in `across`, turn it into a character value and then use `coalesce` to combine the several newly generated columns into one. Note, since `coalese` doesn't work correctly with `across` yet, we have to use `do.call`. This might hopefully change at some point.

Note also that you might want to make sure to use a really unique naming pattern for the temporary columns in order to not interfer with any potentially existing columns along the way.

And although you are ruling out a `rowwise` solution, I'd be quite interested how it could look. I guess the solution below woulnd't perform better at magnitudes than `rowwise`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(na.omit(df$field_name)), ~as.character(.), .names = "{.col}_temp"),
         field_value = do.call(coalesce, across(ends_with("_temp")))) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_temp"))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  category stage is_solid saturation is_vaccinated field_name field_value
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>         <dbl> <lgl>         <chr>      <chr>      
1 oncology I     TRUE             NA TRUE          stage      I          
2 covid19  <NA>  NA               95 FALSE         saturation 95         
3 other    <NA>  NA               NA TRUE          <NA>       <NA>
```

---

Update based on new data example from TO. It's a bit more involved now and could be done with a `pivot_longer/wider` roundtrip.

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(na.omit(df$field_name)), ~as.character(.), .names = "{.col}_temp")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("_temp")) %>%
  filter(str_detect(name, field_name) | (is.na(field_name) & is.na(value))) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  mutate(field_value = do.call(coalesce, across(ends_with("_temp")))) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_temp"))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  category stage is_solid saturation is_vaccinated field_name field_value
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>         <dbl> <lgl>         <chr>      <chr>      
1 oncology I     TRUE             NA TRUE          stage      I          
2 covid19  II    NA               95 FALSE         saturation 95         
3 other    III   NA               NA TRUE          NA         NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried a `rowwise` solution, similar to the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299594/add-columns-dynamically-to-rowwise-tibble-throws-must-return-compatible-vectors/69300850#69300850), but it was too slow

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, will add an example to my question.

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about `str_sub(name, 0, -6) == field_name` instead of `str_detect`. Regex seems like an overkill when an exact  match would suffice. `-6` is due to the `_temp` suffix.

Comment: If you go with "_temp", then str_sub sounds good. The current solution is more generalizable, though. But generally feel free to use and edit to your liking, of course.

Comment: Right, I guess the most robust solution would be to generate a random string for the suffix instead of hard-coding `_temp`.